# Why we have to use $.noConflict() in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, clientscript

I know we are using $.noConflict() to overcome other plugin conflicts.
For example, if some new plugin use the $ symbol as a variable it will override. so, we are using like below

```
var $j=$.noConflict();
```

But, i am having doubt here, We can archive this using below code itself then why $.noConflict(); needed?

```
 var $j=$;
```

Thanks advance. Kindly explain major different

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Comment: Thanks but, i am still doubt as per my question

Comment: I guess if you can use `$.noConflict()` instead of `jQuery.noConflict()` it makes no difference, since `$` has no conflict at the time you're using it there is nothing the `noConflict` function of jQuery can restore `$` to.

Comment: Now i got clear idea about it . Thanks @xander

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you got detailed information about why:

> Many JavaScript libraries use $ as a function or variable name, just
>   as jQuery does. In jQuery's case, $ is just an alias for jQuery, so
>   all functionality is available without using $. If you need to use
>   another JavaScript library alongside jQuery, return control of $ back
>   to the other library with a call to $.noConflict(). **Old references of**
>   **$ are saved during jQuery initialization; noConflict() simply restores**
>   **them.**

It's from jQuery and there is even more information: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

**Update after comment**

From jQuery code https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js if you search for `noConflict` you will find

```
noConflict: function( deep ) {
        if ( window.$ === jQuery ) {
            window.$ = _$;
        }

        if ( deep && window.jQuery === jQuery ) {
            window.jQuery = _jQuery;
        }

        return jQuery;
    },
```

In simple: This checks if global `$` or global `jQuery` has already been used. Either way it will return jQuery. So you can not just do `var $j=$;` cause `$` may already has conflicts. The `noConflict()` is what you need.

Comment: No still i am not clear. As per the reference i understand the use of this. My only question here is we can archive that without $.noconfict() . So, kindly give clear explanation if you have it

Comment: No it's not the same without. Problems may occur as soon as they would have conflicts. Means as soon as mutiple things try to use the `$` from global scope then `var $j=$;` would not work cause `$` already has conflicts.

Comment: @NatarajanVeerasekaran updated the answer. Let me know if that makes now sense for you?

Comment: Thanks guys. Now, i got a better idea @caramba

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use another JavaScript library alongside **jQuery**, return control of $ back to the other library with a call to $**.noConflict().** This technique is especially effective in conjunction with the **.ready()** method's ability to alias the **jQuery** object, as within callback passed to **.ready()** you can use $ if you wish without fear of conflicts later

**Examples of using noConflict in different ways**

**Type 01**
    var j = jQuery.noConflict();

```
// Do something with jQuery
j( "div p" ).hide();

// Do something with another library's $()
$( "content" ).style.display = "none";
```

**Type 02**

```
jQuery.noConflict();
(function( $ ) {
  $(function() {
    // More code using $ as alias to jQuery
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks Suventhan Nantha . I got a better idea.

Comment: @NatarajanVeerasekaran can you upvote my answer if you are happy with my answer?

Comment: @Suventhan Nantha i thought, you only did that clear explanation. i didn't notice content during voting. Anyway both have correct answer. But, comparing the explantion "caramba" gave detailed one

Comment: @NatarajanVeerasekaran but you can still upvote my answer so that I can get some votes since my answer is correct.